# Partial Derivative of Mixed Hadamard Root

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Given $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 3}$, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\mathbf{1}\in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$  and $\mathbf{1}$ is a matrix with all the elements equal to 1. The function is $\mathbf{f}=\sqrt{\left(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \odot \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}\right)\mathbf{1}}$, where $\odot$ is Hadamard product, and $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is Hadamard root (**elements-wise square root**). How to compute $\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}$?

---

The above question has a specific meaning. The vector $\mathbf{f}$ can be seen as a length column vector, that is each element of which is a length of a vector, such as $\mathbf{f} = \left[\begin{array}{l}
||\mathbf{e}_{1}|| \\
||\mathbf{e}_{2}|| \\
\vdots \\
||\mathbf{e}_{n}||
\end{array}\right]$, where vector $\mathbf{e}_{i} = (x_{i}, y_{i}, z_{i})$. So $\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}$ is actually the derivative of the length of some vectors w.r.t it's coordinate.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative you ask is a third-order tensor.
We can easily compute
$\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial \mathbf{X}}$
where $f_n$ is the $n$-th component of
the vector $\mathbf{f}$.

Note that
$f_n = \| \mathbf{y}_n \|$
where
$\mathbf{y}_n = 
\mathbf{a}_n \mathbf{X}$
is a 1-by-3 row vector
and
$\mathbf{a}_n$ is the
$n$-th row vector of $\mathbf{A}$.

From here
\begin{eqnarray*}
df_n
&=& \frac{1}{f_n}
\mathbf{y}_n : d\mathbf{y}_n = \frac{1}{f_n}
\mathbf{y}_n : \mathbf{a}_n d\mathbf{X}
\end{eqnarray*}
The colon operator stands for the
Frobenius inner product.
The derivative is thus

$$
\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
=
\frac{1}{\| \mathbf{a}_n \mathbf{X} \|}
\mathbf{a}_n^T \mathbf{y}_n
$$

Comment: Thanks you! Is that the denominator layout used in the final result?

Comment: I would say yes: denominator-layout notation

Comment: So compute each $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial \mathbf{X}}$, then fill it in $
\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{X}} =\left[\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial \mathbf{X}} & \ldots & \frac{\partial f_{n}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
\end{array}\right]
$, that's it?

Comment: you have to concatenate it in the third dimension as a third-order tensor.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\e{{\large\varepsilon}}
\def\o{{\large\tt1}}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\!\bR{#1}}
$
The requested gradient is a third-order **tensor**,
which can be obtained by calculating the vector-valued derivatives
$$\eqalign{
f\odot f &= \BR{(AX)\odot(AX)}\,\o 
 \quad\doteq\; \diag{AXX^TA^T} \\
2f\odot \g{f}{X_{ij}} &=
\BR{2(AX)\odot(AE_{ij})}\,\o \\
\g{f}{X_{ij}}
 &= \Diag{f}^{-1}\cdot\BR{(AX)\odot(AE_{ij})}\,\o \\
 &= \Diag{f}^{-1}\cdot\diag{AE_{ij}X^TA^T} \\
}$$
and summing them
$$\eqalign{
\g{f}{X} &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^3\LR{\g{f}{X_{ij}}}\star E_{ij}
\;\in\bbR{(n)\times n\times 3} \\
}$$
where $E_{ij}\in\bbR{n\times 3}$ is a standard basis matrix with component $(i,j)$ equal to $\tt1$ and all others equal to zeros, while $(\star)$ is the tensor product.

Or, as Steph has done, one can use matrix-valued derivatives for the construction
$$\eqalign{
\g{f_k}{X} &= {A^T\,\Diag{\e_k\oslash f}\;AX} \\
\g{f}{X} &=
 \sum_{k=1}^n \e_{k}\star\LR{\g{f_k}{X}}
 \;\in\bbR{n\times(n\times 3)} \\
}$$
where $\e_{k}\in\bbR{n}$ is a standard basis vector with component $k$ equal to $\tt1$ and zeros elsewhere and $(\oslash)$ denotes Hadamard division.

In either case, note that you have a sum of
$\,\big({\rm vector} \star {\rm matrix}\big)\,$ terms.

---

Perhaps this scalar-valued derivative provides the clearest answer
$$\eqalign{
\g{f_k}{X_{ij}}
 &= \e_i^TA^T\,\Diag{\e_k\oslash f}\;AXe_j \\
}$$
This result can be rearranged into many equivalent forms
$$\eqalign{
\g{f_k}{X_{ij}}
 &= E_{ij}:\BR{A^T\,\Diag{\e_k\oslash f}\;AX} \\
 &= \LR{AE_{ij}X^TA^T}:\Diag{\e_k\oslash f} \\
 &= \diag{AE_{ij}X^TA^T}:\bR{\e_k\oslash f} \\
 &= \diag{AE_{ij}X^TA^T}:\Diag{f}^{-1}\e_k \\
 &= \e_k^T\Diag{f}^{-1}\diag{AE_{ij}X^TA^T} \\
}$$
where $e_j$ is a standard basis vector for $\bbR 3$ and $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product.